# Filter RDD to return

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My function (test_rdd.cartesian(test_rdd)) returns RDDs of value pairs like this:

```
[((1, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (3, 0))]
```

I need to get rid of those entries where both elements are equal (e.g.: ...,((1, 0), (1, 0)),...).

As I just started working with rdd and spark, I might be missing something really basic.

Can you give me an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code for Scala:

```
val array = Array(((1, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (3, 0)))

val rdd = sc.parallelize(array) // creating RDD
val filteredRDD = rdd.filter(row => row._1  != row._2) //accessing element in tuple 
filteredRDD.collect() // calling action
```

Result:

```
Array[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] = Array(((1,0),(2,0)), ((1,0),(3,0)), ((2,0),(1,0)), ((2,0),(3,0)), ((3,0),(1,0)), ((3,0),(2,0)))
```

For Pyspark following code can be used:

```
array = [((1, 0), (1, 0)), ((1, 0), (2, 0)), ((1, 0), (3, 0)), ((2, 0), (1, 0)), ((2, 0), (2, 0)), ((2, 0), (3, 0)), ((3, 0), (1, 0)), ((3, 0), (2, 0)), ((3, 0), (3, 0))]

rdd = sc.parallelize(array) # creating RDD
filteredRDD = rdd.filter(lambda row : row[0]  != row[1]) #accessing element in tuple 
filteredRDD.collect() # calling action
```

Result:

```
[((1, 0), (2, 0)),
 ((1, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((2, 0), (3, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((3, 0), (2, 0))]
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, although I get an error for the syntax. I ended up doing: test_rdd.cartesian(test_rdd).filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1]).collect()

Comment: @val_to_many: updated ans with pyspark code. you can filter without using cartesian